Split JavaScript file running in JavaScript Shell
I would like to refactor some very large JavaScript project into smaller files. However, using modules fails when trying to run the main file in the SpiderMonkey JavaScript shell:
user@host:~/git/project$ ../jsshell-81_0_1/js main.js
smash.js:1:0 SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module:
smash.js:1:0 import utilities from './utils.js'
smash.js:1:0 ^

I think the issue is that I would need to import the main file in the HTML file as module but that's not possible when using the SpiderMonkey JavaScript shell (and that's not changeable as my development host is headless).
Is there any other way to solve this?

Any particular reason it has to be Spidermonkey, and not Node or Deno or Bun?

Why are you using the Spidermonkey shell at all? From what I can tell, it's more of a tool for debugging the engine, not for actually running an application. So can't you just switch to an environment that supports loading modules natively?

If necessary, just run a bundler tool on your module project and you'll get back the same huge single script file.
